# Simplify this code? Get all files from folder & it's subfolders-- Current code is timing out

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a drive folder that's got about 1500 Google Slides within one parent folder, and multiple child folders. I've been using this script, but it's stopped working because it times out (our folders have grown considerably). Is there any easy way around this? I'm needing links to all of these files populated (with their file names) onto ONE tab of a Google Sheet.

Here's my current script (got it from somewhere online and modified it a bit; I am not super experienced/trained with writing code).

```
var folderId = '1TO3e8ilnqNuxBcvTw8D_3RsDxDzMwvX7';
// Main function 1: List all folders, & write into the current sheet.
function listFolders() {
  getFolderTree(folderId, false);
}
// Main function 2: List all files & folders, & write into the current sheet.
function listAll() {
  getFolderTree(folderId, true);
}

// =================
// Get Folder Tree.
function getFolderTree(folderId, listAll) {
  try {
    // Get folder by id.
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

    // Initialise the sheet.
    var file, data, sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.clear();
    // Get files and folders
    getChildFolders(parentFolder.getName(), parentFolder, data, sheet, listAll);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
}
// Get the list of files and folders and their metadata in recursive mode.
function getChildFolders(parentName, parent, data, sheet, listAll) {
  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
  // List folders inside the folder.
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    // Logger.log("Folder Name: " + childFolder.getName());
    data = [
      parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(),
      childFolder.getName(),
    ];

    // List files inside the folder.
    var files = childFolder.getFiles();
    while (listAll & files.hasNext()) {
      var childFile = files.next();
      // Logger.log("File Name: " + childFile.getName());
      data = [
        childFile.getUrl(),
        childFile.getName(),
      ];
      // Write
      sheet.appendRow(data);
    }
    // Recursive call of the subfolder
    getChildFolders(parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(), childFolder, data, sheet, listAll);
  }
}
```

Comment: You want all files and folders or can you provide some criteria and schedule it to run daily/weekly etc? Instead of fetching everything in one shot, keep an incremental model where you search for files older than a day or something like this. Run this code (via Scheduler) every day so it will keep on adding lines to your sheet.

Comment: Use `setValues()` instead of `appendRow()` and use batch operations with `getContinuationToken()`

Comment: Okay, thank you! That is a great idea! I'm just having a hard time pulling all the files in the first place. I'm also a COMPLETE novice to using/writing script. So, I don't even know what you mean by getContinuationToken. I'll look on the reference website though! I appreciate your help!!